# Methods of the same name and inheritance, Python

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

I have an odd question, and seeing as the real context is fairly complex I've made a simple example. I have two classes **Base** and **Child**. Each share a method of the the same name **go**. What I want the **Child** class to be able to do is inherit the **go** method from **Base**. However, when I call the **go** method on **Child** I want it to do some things (In this case multiply the attribute **A** by 2), then call the **go** method that it inherited from **Base**.

In this example calling **go** on **Base** would print 35, while I want **Child** to print 70.

```
class Base :
    def __init__ (self) :
        self.A = 35

    def go (self) :
        print self.A


class Child (Base) :
    def __init__ (self) :
        Base.__init__(self)

    def go (self) :
        self.A = self.A * 2

        # Somehow call Base's **go** method, which would print 70.
```

I understand that it's typically not a good idea to do this (seeing as it could be confusing), however in the context of what I'm doing it makes sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is absolutely a fine thing to do. What you're looking for is [`super()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super).

```
class Child (Base):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(Child, self).__init__()

    def go(self):
        self.A = self.A * 2
        super(Child, self).go()
```

In Python 3 you can use it without arguments because it will detect the correct ones automatically.

Edit: `super()` is for new-style classes, which you should use anyway. Just declare any class which doesn't inherit from another as inheriting from `object`:

```
class Base(object):
```

Also, all those extra spaces before and after parenthesis are not considered good python style, see [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Hmm, in 2.7 this doesn't seem to work. I get the error **TypeError: must be type, not classobj**.

Comment: It works. You need to use new-style classes (they're better, anyway). Just change `class Base :` to `class Base(object) :`.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Edits need to be substantive; active reading isn't an acceptable reason to make trivial edits.